# Gray out/grayscale element and nested elements

Tags: css, html, inheritance, polymer, web-component

My goal is to show my Polymer element in "disabled" state by graying out/grayscaling all the html elements in it. The problem is that I have nested polymer elements.
Using grayscale filter would be a perfect approach but it doesn't work in IE10+ (and workarounds don't work well with text).
Is there any other ways?

Comment: Could you please post some code, this question would have 10s of answers that never fits your situation so some of your code could help us identify the problem and suggest a workaround.

Comment: I can't share code or mockup due to corporate policy :( Will try to make my own sample.

Comment: Did you consider using the `paper-dialog` element with backdrop? There is a sample available: [polymer-paper-dialog-example](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/components/paper-dialog/demo.html) (click on "Modal dialog with backdrop and actions" button) The source may at least lead you in the right direction, if you do not wish a message to appear in the center.

Comment: No, the problem is this is not that we need. We need "disabled" state for the most of the ui elements.